# How to avoid to see background behind tableView Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have the following problem scrolling down through my tableView.
I want to avoid seeing the white background behind the tableView.

How I can fix it? Thanks[image: Image here]

Comment: set the tableview background color to ur desired color. or set a background image for the table view.

Comment: you just set height as same as your view height in UI so it is not display background white

Comment: What background _do_ you want to see?

Comment: I had set a background color as Teja Nandamuri says. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have taken `Grouped tableview` then try with Changing `TableView Style` to `Plain` from `Grouped`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to make the cell transparent , add this function where you load your table.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)
}
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypcXw.png) this becomes this [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzo1x.png)

Comment: Why use `UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)` instead of `UIColor.clearColor()`? Just curious.

Comment: I use to give different intensity alpha